# How to get the body of Chatter Files in Apex?

Tags: apex, chatter, feeditem

When I'm trying to do e.g. in either code or the Developer Console

```
SELECT Id, Type, Body, Title, ContentData From FeedItem where Type = 'ContentPost' LIMIT 1
```

I get

> No such column 'ContentData' on entity 'FeedItem'. If you are
>   attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after
>   the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call
>   for the appropriate names.

And indeed when I click 'Open Resource' and then FeedItem I somehow don't see the ContentData field being listed... Anybody an idea why not or what I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**As per the doc**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm)

This field only Available in API version 35.0 and earlier only.

> Available in API version 35.0 and earlier only. This field is required
>   if Type is ContentPost. Encoded file data in any format, and can’t be
>   0 bytes. Setting this field automatically sets Type to ContentPost.

Since you are using Developer console.. I think this query performed in latest API(i.e. 36v )

The proper way to do this in v36 is to first create a FeedItem, but without any ContentData, i.e. an empty FeedItem. Then create a ContentVersion with VersionData (which under water creates a ContentDocument). Then create a FeedAttachment that relates the created ContentDocument to the FeedItem. It's a bit of a hassle, but it works.

Comment: So... how are we supposed to query that data in API v36? Thanks!

Comment: @WillemMulder  I am not sure.. If you want to use this field in apex class just change the API version...

Comment: upon further inspection it appears there is now "FeedAttachment" which is a junction record between ContentDocument and a FeedItem. I'm going to try to get that to work; then report back.

Comment: So I got it to work, and updated the answer to explain what needs doing. It's not as easy as I hoped though :-)

Comment: @WillemMulder Thanks.. Really good you solved your own issue.

Comment: @WillemMulder Just for a FYI If you create a FeedItem with an attachment(means if you post a chatter with any files). Then one FeedItem created and a child feedItem attachment created with the file..

Comment: Really? That should not be necessary according to the docs, because that would theoretically result in two different posts. But that does not happen in practice, apparently? How are these two FeedItems related?

Comment: @WillemMulder no Basically if you post an attachment one FeedItem created and one feedItemAttachment created(this is child of feeditem).

Comment: Ah you mean the FeedAttachment that I also mentioned in the answer? Yes, it relates the FeedItem to a ContentDocument (i.e. the attachment) so that it shows in the feed

Comment: @WillemMulder ohh is it. I didn't notice that.. cool thanks.

Comment: No problem :-) It has become a bit complicated, but at least this allows us to couple multiple attachments to one feeditem, which could be beneficial at some point.